Unbiased test for homogeneity of means of exponenential samples
Given $K$ independent samples of $Y_{i1},\dots,Y_{in_i} \ \text{i.i.d.} \ \sim Exp(\lambda_i)$ with $i=1,\dots, K$ and $n_i$ the size of the $i$-th sample, is there any statistics with analytically known distribution to perform an exact test for following hypotesis?
$$\begin{cases}H_0: \lambda_1=\dots=\lambda_K \\ H1:\bar{H_0}\end{cases}$$
For two samples is quite easy, since $2n_1\lambda_1\bar{Y_1}\sim \chi^2_{2n_1}$ and $2n_2\lambda_2\bar{Y_2}\sim \chi^2_{2n_2}$ ($\bar{Y_1}$ and $\bar{Y_2}$ are the average within the two groups), hence $\frac{\bar{Y_1}}{\bar{Y_2}} \underset{H_0}{\sim}F_{2n_1, 2n_2}$.
For multiple samples we could suppose to restrict the problem to paired data ($n_1=n_2=\dots=n_K=n$) and try different statistics:

$\displaystyle\max_{j,k}{\frac{\bar{Y_j}}{\bar{Y_k}}}\quad $but this is probably impossible to solve paper and pen, without Monte Carlo methods;
ANOVA test, with the same formula as for the nullity test in the linear normal regression $\frac{(RSS_0-RSS)/(K-1)}{RSS/(K\cdot n-K)}$, where it should be quite clear that $RSS_0$ is the total deviance $\sum_{i=1}^K\sum_{j=1}^n(Y_{ij}-\bar Y)^2$ and $RSS$ is the the Residual Sum of Squares $\sum_{i=1}^K\sum_{j=1}^n(Y_{ij}-\bar{Y_i})^2$, and which the closer to zero the less likely we refuse the null, but still couldn't come up with a close formula for the distribution;
the most promising seems to be the loglikelihood-ratio test $$W_p^{H_0}=2\left[\hat l-\hat l_p\right]=2\left[l(\hat\lambda_1,\dots,\hat\lambda_K)-l(\underbrace{\hat\lambda_0,\dots,\hat\lambda_0}_{K})\right]$$
where $\lambda_0$ is the unknown common value of $\lambda$ under the null.
It's easy to find out that the generic $\hat\lambda_i=\frac{1}{\bar{Y_i}}$, while $\hat\lambda_0 = \frac{1}{\bar Y} = \frac{K}{\sum_{i=1}^K\bar{Y_i}}$.
With some basic algebra we can find that
$$W_p^{H_0} = 2nK\left[\ln\left(\frac{\bar{Y_1}+\dots+\bar{Y_K}}{K}\right)-\frac{\ln(\bar{Y_1})+\dots+\ln(\bar{Y_K})}{K}\right]$$
or alternatively
$$W_p^{H_0} = 2nK\cdot\ln\left(\frac{\bar Y}{\left(\bar{Y_1}\cdot\dots\cdot\bar{Y_K}\right)^\frac{1}{k}}\right)$$
We know that under the null hypotesis this distributes aymptotically as a $\chi^2_{K-1}$, but can we build an exact distribution? I just considered the argument of the logarithm,
$$\frac{\bar Y}{\left(\bar{Y_1}\times\dots\times\bar{Y_K}\right)^{1/K}}$$ since it doesn't affect the result ($\ln(\cdot)$ is an increasing function and we reject $H_0$ for high values). The numerator of this statistics has also a neat distribution, what I miss is that sort of Mixed Arithmetic-Geometric mean at the denominator.
We notice that because of AM-GM Inequality the statistics is always greater or equal to one, but then I saw through some Monte Carlo simulations and a visual analysis with R that the statistics fits very very well a Gamma distribution, shifted off by one, where I chose as estimators for the parameters of the Gamma distribution the MMEs (If $X\sim Gamma(\alpha, \beta)$, $\alpha>0$ shape parameter and $\beta>0$ rate parameter, $\mathbb E[X]=\frac{\alpha}{\beta}$ and $Var(X)=\frac{\alpha}{\beta^2}$, therefore $\tilde\beta=\frac{\bar X}{S^2_X}$ and $\tilde\alpha=\tilde\beta\cdot\bar X$ are consistent estimators for $\beta$ and $\alpha$ respectively). Given $\lambda_0=2$, $n=15$ and $K=4$, after generating 100.000 test statistics through Monte Carlo, I got $\tilde\alpha=1.42$ and $\tilde\beta=54.36$, and these are the graphical results:



Why does it work so fine? Are there any other means to answer to the first question I set? Which one is the most statistically powerful?
I will thank anyone who is willing to share his ideas, results or some useful literature to go into detail about this topic.

Of course homogneity of the means implies homogeneity of the rate parameter $\lambda$, as well as of the variance, which is $1/\lambda^2$ in the exponential distribution, hence the tag "heteroschedasticity".
